# Cant get my google maps widget to load. It worked perfectly until I decided to have it hidden (using .hide)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

My google maps widget worked perfectly until I decided to have it hidden (using .hide jquery ). You can click a div to reveal the widget (using .toggle jquery). Now, however, the map does not load inside the container. It's like it thinks its still hidden. Any Ideas? If I click on another tab on my browser, and go straight back to the page, then the map is loaded.

```
           <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="sss/sss.css" type="text/css" media="all">
        <script src="includes/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="sss/sss.min.js"></script>
        <script src="includes/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script>
                  $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#slidemenu ul").hover(function(){
                      $(".item").toggle("slide", { direction: "right"  }, 400 );
                  });
                  }); 

                  $(document).ready(function(){
                    $(".menubutton").mouseover(function(){ 
                      $('.menubutton #line').css( "background-color", "orange")
                  })
                                .mouseout(function() { 
                      $('.menubutton #line').css( "background-color", "white")
                  });
                  }); 

                  $(document).ready(function(){
                  $(".item").mouseover(function(){ 
                      $('.menubutton #line').css( "background-color", "orange")
                  })
                            .mouseout(function() { 
                      $('.menubutton #line').css( "background-color", "white")
                  });
                  });

                  $(document).ready(function(){
                  $(".oneitem").mouseover(function(){ 
                      $('.menubutton #line').css( "background-color", "orange")
                  })
                               .mouseout(function() { 
                      $('.menubutton #line').css( "background-color", "white")
                  });
                  });


                 </script>
            <script>
            function initialize() {
              var mapProp = {
                center:new google.maps.LatLng(54.149517, -8.278809),
                zoom:13,
                mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
              };
              var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("fermoy"),mapProp);
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(54.149517, -8.278809);
               var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                   position: point,
                   title:"Fermoy"
               });

               // To add the marker to the map, call setMap();
               marker.setMap(map);

            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

            </script>
                <script>
            function initialize() {
              var mapProp = {
                center:new google.maps.LatLng(54.149517, -8.278809),
                zoom:13,
                mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
              };
              var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map1"),mapProp);
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(54.149517, -8.278809);
               var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                   position: point,
                   title:"Map"
               });

               // To add the marker to the map, call setMap();
               marker.setMap(map);



            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

            </script>
            <script>

        function initialize() {
            var mapProp = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(56.104607, -6.698879),
                zoom: 13,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map2"), mapProp);
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(56.104607, -5.698879);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: point,
                title: "Map"
            });



        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);



            </script>
             <script>
            function initialize() {
              var mapProp = {
                center:new google.maps.LatLng(53.344573,-6.370321),
                zoom:13,
                mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
              };
              var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map3"),mapProp);
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(53.344573,-6.370321);
               var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                   position: point,
                   title:"map"
               });

               // To add the marker to the map, call setMap();
               marker.setMap(map);

            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

            </script>




        <script type="text/javascript">
                   function diffImage(img) 
        {
           if(img.src.match(/up/)) img.src = "images/down.png";
           else img.src = "images/up.png";
        }
        </script>
        <script>
             $(document).ready(function(){
                   $(".toshow").hide();
                   });


                   $(document).ready(function(){
                   $("#button").click(function(){
                   $(".toshow").toggle();
                   });
                   });
        </script>





        <style>
                    /* Standard Menu */
                      body {
                          margin: 0px;
                          padding: 0px;

                           }
                      header {
                          background-color: black;
                          height: 60px;
                          width: 100%;
                          position: fixed;
                          z-index: 100;
                           } /* This is our finished menu */
                     .blackbar {
                          height: 60px;
                          width: 100%;
                          background-color: black;
                          } /* As the menu is not fixed this keeps a black bar behind when the menu is at the veru top */
                      .logo img {
                          height: 40px; 
                          background-color:black; 
                          float: left;  
                          margin-top: 0px; 
                          padding:9px;
                          margin-left:  30px;
                          } /* The McMahons Logo */
                      #navdiv li {
                          display: inline-block;
                          vertical-align: middle;
                          }
                      #navdiv a {
                          text-decoration: none;
                          color: white;
                          text-transform: uppercase;
                          font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
                          }
                      #navdiv a:active {
                          color:orange;
                          } /* Current Page Link Highlighted Orange */
                      #navdiv a:hover {
                          color: orange;
                          } /* Link Hovered Orange */
                      nav {
                          width: auto;
                          float: right;
                          word-spacing: 30px;
                          height: 60px;
                          min-width: 600px;
                          } /* This is the part of the menu with the page links laid out horizontally */
                      ul {
                          width: 600px;
                          letter-spacing: 0.14em;
                          margin-right: 20px;
                          margin-left: 20px;
                          padding-left: 0px;
                          }  /* List of Links to Pages */     
                    /* Slider Menu */
                        #slidemenu {  /* The Slide In Menu */
                          height: 40px;
                          width: 105px;
                          padding: 0px;
                          margin: 0px;
                          float: right;
                          margin-right: 30px;
                          }
                        #slidemenu a {
                          text-decoration: none;
                          color: white;
                          font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
                          }
                        #slidemenu ul {
                          list-style-type: none; 
                          margin: 0px;
                          padding: 0px; 
                          }
                        #slidemenu ul .item {
                          display: none; 
                          right: 70px; 
                          }    /* Current slidemenu position */
                        .oneitem {  
                            display: block;
                            background-color: black;
                            width: 100px;
                            height: 19px;
                            text-align: center;
                            padding: 19px;            
                           }   /* This is already in place, jQuery doesnt need to bring this in */                 
                        .item {  
                            display: block;
                            z-index: 100;
                            background-color: black;
                            width: 100px;
                            height: 20px;
                            text-align: center;
                            padding: 19px;
                           }  /* jQuery brings this into play, by default it is overtaken by  (#menubutton ul .item) as this is more specific */ 
                    /* MENU BUTTON */
                        .menubutton {
                            background-color: black;
                            visibility: visible;
                            margin-top: 10px;
                            margin-right: 20px; 
                            background-color: black;
                            position: absolute;
                            right: 20px;  
                           }
                        #line {
                            background-color: white;
                            width: 40px;
                            height: 5px;
                            margin: 6px;
                           }             
                    /* RESIZING WINDOW ADJUSTMENTS */
                        @media only screen and (max-width: 950px) {
                        nav{
                            display: none;
                        }
                        } /* Rids Navgation Links when screen is minimized */    
                        @media only screen and (min-width: 950px) {
                        #slidemenu{
                             display: none;
                        }
                        } /* Rids Menu Button when at full-screen */ 
                        @media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
                        .logo img{
                            margin-left: 4px;
                        }
                        } /* Pulls Logo slightly left when screen is highly minimized to prevent Menu Bottom Colliding */ 
                        html, body, #container { height: 100%; }
                        body > #container { height: auto; min-height: 100%; }
                        #footer {
                         clear: both;
                         position: relative;
                         z-index: 10;
                         height: 130px;
                         margin-top: 3em;
                         background-color: black;
                         bottom: 0px;
                           overflow: hidden;

                         }
                        #content { padding-bottom: 3em; }
                        .box{
                          width: 15%;
                          height:124px;
                          display: inline-block;
                          min-width: 200px;
                        }
                        .box h1{
                          font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
                          font-size: 20px;
                        }
                        #social img{
                          width: 60px;
                          height:60px;
                          margin:0px;
                          padding-bottom: 10px;
                        }
                        #social h1{
                            margin-bottom: 5px;
                          padding-left: 53px;
                        }
                        .trusshead h1{
                        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
                        font-size: 60px;
                        text-transform: uppercase;
                        margin:0px;



                        }
                        #fermoy{
                          margin-top: 30px;
                          border: 2px solid black;

                        }


                        #fermoy2, #blanch, #ballyfermott, #portarlington, #limerick, #cork, #dunmanway, #tralee, #galway, #waterford, #coleraine, #derry, #omagh {
                          margin-top: 30px;
                          border: 2px solid black;
                          border-top: 3px solid black;
                          }



                        .text p {
                          font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
                          text-align: center;

                        }
                        .contactboxes {
                          float: left;
                          width: 195px;
                          height: 308px;

                        }
                        .contactboxes h3{
                       font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
                       margin: 0px;
                       margin-top: 35px;

                        }
                          .contactboxes p{
                       font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
                       margin: 0px;

                        }


        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <header>
                 <div class="logo">
                    <img src="images/mclogo.png">
                   </div>
                 <div id="navdiv">
                    <div id="slidemenu">
                      <ul>
                            <li class="menubutton">
                                <div id="line"></div>
                                <div id="line"></div>
                                <div id="line"></div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="oneitem" style="padding-bottom: 22px;"></li>
                            <li class="item" ><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="item"><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
                            <li class="item"><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                            <li class="item"><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                            <li class="item"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <nav>
                      <ul>
                         <li class="hide active"><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>
                         <li class="hide"><a href='products.html'>Products</a></li>
                         <li class="hide"><a href='services.html'>Services</a></li>
                         <li class="hide"><a href='blog.html'>Blog</a></li>
                         <li class="hide"><a href='contact.html'>Contact</a></li>
                         <li class="hide">
                            <a class="fb_icon" href="https://www.facebook.com/mcmahons123?fref=ts" target="_blank">
                            <img src='images/facebook.png' onmouseover="this.src='images/facebookorange.png';" onmouseout="this.src='images/facebook.png';"/></a>
                         </li>
                      </ul>
                    </nav>
                  </div>
             </header>
            <div id="container">
                     <div style="background-color: black; width:100%; height:60px; visibility: hidden;"></div>
              <div id="content">

               <div style="width: 1150px;; margin: 0 auto; height: 30px; margin-top: 20px;">
                  <div style="float:right; "><h2 style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; margin:0px;">Email: &nbsp@hotmail</h2></div>
                  <div style="float: left;"><h2 style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;margin:0px; ">Call: &nbsp12344</h2></div>
                  </div>
                  <div style="width: 100%; margin-top: 0px;">
                      <div style="width: 40px; height: 4px; background-color: black; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="trusshead" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 190px;">
                      <h1>Stack</h1>
                  </div>
                  <div style="width: 100%; margin-top: 1px;">
                      <div style="width: 40px; height: 4px; background-color: black; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div  class="text" style="width: 520px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 50px;">
                      <p>123 Testing 123</p>
                  </div>

                  <div style="margin:0 auto; width: 780px; height: 400px; margin-top: 50px;">
                  <div class="contactboxes">
                      <h3>Plant</h3>
                      <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
                      <p style="margin-bottom: 10px"> 123<br>Happy Rd,<br>RedHill,<br>Spain</p>
                      <p style="margin-bottom:5px;"> <strong>Email:</strong><br> @google</p>
                      <p style="margin-bottom:5px;"> <strong>Tel:</strong> <br>000000</p>
                      <p> <strong>Fax:</strong> <br>00000</p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="map1" style="width:405px; height:308px; float:right; display:inline;  "></div>
                  </div>

                             <div style="width: 430px; height: 30px; margin:0 auto;"><p style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif">Click the arrow to expand a list of maps.
                             </p></div>
                             <div id="button" style="width: 30px; margin:0 auto;">
                             <img src="images/down.png" id="image1" style="height: 30px;" onclick=diffImage(this) /></div>
                             <div class="toshow">
                  <div style="width: 90px; margin: 0 auto;"><h2 style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; ">Maps</h2></div>

                  <div style="margin:0 auto; width: 780px; height: 1030px; ">

                  <div style="width:100%; height: 405px;">
                  <div class="contactboxes">
                      <h3>Dub</h3>
                      <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
                      <p style="margin-bottom: 10px"> 123<br>Happy Rd,<br>RedHill,<br>Spain</p>
                      <p style="margin-bottom:5px;"> <strong>Email:</strong><br> @google</p>
                      <p style="margin-bottom:5px;"> <strong>Tel:</strong> <br>000000</p>
                      <p> <strong>Fax:</strong> <br>00000</p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="map2" style="width:405px; height:308px; float:right; display:inline; "></div>
                  </div>

                  <div style="width:100%; height: 405px;">
                   <div class="contactboxes">
                      <h3>Dub</h3>
                      <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
                      <p style="margin-bottom: 10px"> 123<br>Happy Rd,<br>RedHill,<br>Spain</p>
                      <p style="margin-bottom:5px;"> <strong>Email:</strong><br> @google</p>
                      <p style="margin-bottom:5px;"> <strong>Tel:</strong> <br>000000</p>
                      <p> <strong>Fax:</strong> <br>00000</p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="map3" style="width:405px; height:308px; float:right; display:inline; "></div></div>


                  </div>





                   </div>
                   </div>

            <div id="footer">
                <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 705px;">                                                                    <!--To Centre Boxes-->
                    <div class="box">                                                                                                      <!--Box-->
                        <h1 style="color: white; padding-top:40px; margin-left: 40px;">News</h1>
                        <img src="images/black.jpg" style="width: 190px; height: 35px; ">   <!--Black Box under writing - keeps writing off bottom-->
                     </div>
                  <div style="width: 40px; display: inline-block;"></div>                                                            <!--Space Div-->
                  <div class="box" id="social">                                                                                            <!--Box-->
                            <h1 style="color: white;">Follow Us</h1>
                            <div style="width: 90px; height: 2px; background-color: white; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-left: 51px"></div>  <!--Line-->
                            <div style="width: 128px; margin-left: 33px;">                                     <!-- Containing div for two circles-->
                                <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><img src="images/facebookfooter.png"></a>
                                <img src="images/twitterfooter.png">
                             </div>
                   </div>
                  <div style="width: 40px; display: inline-block"></div>                                                             <!--Space Div-->
                  <div class="box">                                                                                                        <!--Box-->
                    <img src="images/ce.png" style="height: 30px; margin-left: 75px; ">
                    <img src="images/black.jpg" style="width: 190px; height: 40px; ">       <!--Black Box under writing - keeps writing off bottom-->
                   </div>
                 </div>
             </div>    
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Hello, Are you still having trouble with this issue? If you were able to resolve it please post an answer explaining your steps.

Comment: Your JSFiddle worked perfectly but for some reason It wouldn't work for me. I'll post all my code now if you want to have a look at it

Comment: I dont' see the `google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize")` add it to your `$("#button").click()` function as I did in the jsfiddle.

Comment: I tried it but couldnt work it still, I took what I had added in out of the code so you could see what I had

Comment: I GOT IT! I just didn't make the correlation between "map" in  "google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize")" and the id of the map. I just thought it was a general resizing of all maps on the page. Pretty stupid i know, only new to this though. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things here.

One is that your div id is `maps` but your `getElementById` refers to `map`

The second is that google maps is trying to figure out the height and width of your container div and it isn't able to do so. You should specify a explicit height and width for your div like:  `<div id="map" style="height:500px;width:500px"></div>`

The third is that a resize takes place when you unhide the div which you need to inform the map about via `google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");`

With these changes your code should work as expected.
I've created a jsfiddle over at https://jsfiddle.net/tjvr5uaq/1/ to demonstrate.